# Apache spark scala Exception handling

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, try-catch

How do I do Exception handling in Spark - Scala for invalid records
Here is my code:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile(file)
val rowRDD = rawData.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(",")))
val rowRDMapped = rowRDD.map { x => x.get(1), x.get(10) }
val DF = rowRDMapped.toDF("ID", "name" )
```

Everything works fine if the input data is fine, If I dont have enough fields, I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

I am trying to put try-catch around, but I am not able to skip the records with invalid data, via try catch

```
val rowRDMapped = rowRDD.map { try {
                                    x => x.get(1), x.get(10) 
                                    }catch {
                                        println("Invalid Data")
                                        //Here it expects to return ROW, but I am not sure what to do here, since I dont want any data to be returned.
                                    }
                             }
```

Please let me know how to solve the issue with try catch and if there is any better solution, that also would help lot

Comment: What do you want? Skip too short lines?

Comment: @Zernike, thanks for looking, Yes, I need to skip the short lines, which causes Index out of bound exception.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile(file)
val rowRDD = rawData.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(",")))
val rowRDMapped = rowRDD.filter(_.length >= 11).map(x => x.get(1), x.get(10))
```

better to use [collect](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect[U](f:PartialFunction[T,U])(implicitevidence$29:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) (don't confuse with [other function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect():Array[T]))

```
val rowRDMapped = rowRDD.collect{x if x.length >= 11 => x.get(1), x.get(10)}
```

Comment: Doesnt matter for an answer. Real requirements may be any. For this example correct is `11` because Row has zero-based indices.

Comment: yes you are right. I was going to write 11 too but I just mistakenly wrote 9. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use try catch as below and filter later on

```
val rawData = sc.textFile(file)
val rowRDD = rawData.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(",")))
val rowRDMapped = rowRDD.map(x => (Try(x.get(1).toString) getOrElse "blank", Try(x.get(10).toString) getOrElse "blank"))
val DF = rowRDMapped.toDF("ID", "name").filter($"name" =!= "blank")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of try-catch you can use [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html)

Code below will filter out data lines which don't have enough fields and get dataframe with remaining ones.

```
val rawData = sc.textFile(line)
val rowRDD = rawData.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(",")))
val rowRDMapped = rowRDD.flatMap{ x => Try(x.getString(1), x.getString(10)).toOption }
val DF = rowRDMapped.toDF("ID", "name")
```