# How can I catch a BlockMissingException when reading files using Spark sc.textFile?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

When reading text files stored on HDFS, if I run into a BlockMissingException (or some other exception) while reading those files with sc.textFile, how can I catch the error and proceed with an emptyRDD?

The reason I might run into a BlockMissingException is if, for example, the files are stored on HDFS with a replication factor of 1 and a data node goes down.

Consider the following minimum example code:

```
    val myRDD: RDD[String] =
        try {
            sc.textFile("hdfs:///path/to/fileWithMissingBlock")
        } catch {
            case e: BlockMissingException =>
                println("missing block, continuing with empty RDD")
                sc.emptyRDD[String]
            case e: Throwable =>
                println("unknown exception, continuting with empty RDD")
                sc.emptyRDD[String]
        }

    val nLines = myRDD.count
    println("There are " + nLines + " lines")
```

This program fails instead of producing the desired count of 0, in the case the file has a missing block. Here is the exception I recieve

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost):
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: 
>   ...

I understand that spark may run things out of order so exception handling may be be better situated within an RDD.map (e.g. [Apache spark scala Exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116513/apache-spark-scala-exception-handling)), but what if the RDD hasn't been created yet?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call `sc.textFile("hdfs:///path/to/fileWithMissingBlock")`, spark doesn't do anything (lazy evaluation) i.e: read file from your filesystem.

It actually execute when a `action` is called, here is then `count` method. That monment exeception come in.